# Is there a way to stream wirelessly from a laptop to a TV?

Tags: laptop, hdmi, streaming, tv, terminology

I heard of such a thing like a box or a media player such thing that can connect wirelessly to stream movies from my laptop?

Is there such a thing that can do it? How is the latency on it? I have fast internet so that's not an issue, or is there such a box that connects with Bluetooth for better connection?

I need these box to also be able to browse the internet because I'd like to stream movies from YouTube. I have heard of a thing called boxee, but is that what I'm looking for?

I have windows 7 as my os, with an HDMI out and a GPU with a 555m. My laptop is powerful enough and my internet is 25mbps with a cap of 150GB.

All i would really like to know is what this device is called? A media box?

Comment: Sure.  Just feed the video output into an RF modulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your TV has wifi/ethernet ability and supports DLNA (or "AllShare" if you have a new Samsung TV). Then you can open media file in Windows Media Player and choose "Play to" and then choose your TV.

[image: The "Play to" menu allows you to send the media file to your TV.]

Bluetooth would likely not support the throughput required for high quality media streaming.

You can always setup a Windows Media Center PC and hook it up to the TV. But as I said, if your TV supports DLNA then you can stream over the network. That doesn't really solve the YouTube part though.

Comment: Uhmm. I do have a samsung TV but its not super new, maybe a year or two. I'll check it out if it supports DLNA or "allshare". 

I have a question about the "play to" option. I don't see when I right click on any media, does this option only appear once I get a hook up to the tv?

Comment: I've added a screenshot to my answer. It is done from within Windows Media Player. If you include your TV model, I could be of better assistance. Also, I'm talking about Windows 7 here, not sure about older versions.

Comment: Cool. Also if you have a Samsung SmartTV (TV or Bluray player), that means you can install apps (such as YouTube, Netflix, etc.) See if your remote has a "Smart Hub" button.

Comment: No, it's not that new :P 
I wish. :/

Comment: Hmm...Our Samsung has this feature. Can this enable reading PDFs in our TV?

Comment: For that you would need to connect your PC to the TV using HDMI or another connection. Then, whatever is on the computer screen will be duplicated on the TV.

Answer (score 2):

Swipeit available through samsung website under connected living.
Or, if you have smart TV, go to Samsung Apps and connected living.

Download on your TV; then download the app on your platform (tablet, a phone etc..) then bring up the photos, share them on your TV from your phone or your tablet.

I just "throw" the picture on the TV and my kids really get amazed. They think it is magic.  You will have much fun with it (and with your kids of course). Although, seriously - it works as advertised..  Videos work too.  Best part about it? It is free. You got to like that...!

Answer (score 2):

[Brite View makes a device](http://www.brite-view.com/) that connects to your computer's HDMI output and streams wirelessly to your TV HDMI input.  You can send anything from your computer to the TV and the audio also streams.

I know it works because I bought one.

There are distance and line of sight restrictions that you should read about before purchasing this item. You can also use this same items to wirelessly stream from your cable box that is equipped with HDMI outputs to any TV that has HDMI inputs with the same restrictions.

I have used it to send cable signals to a TV I temporarily put outside and did not have cable available in that location.

Answer (score 0):

Add any XBMC installed device to the TV, (raspberry PI with xbmc, AppleTV2 jailbroken) switch on airplay under services. Now any iOS6 device or airplay compatible device will have a square with a triangle on top in youtube etc. Select this to connect to the TV.